# Create Execute file for JavaFX project (Gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, jar, launch4j

I need to create a `.exe` file for my project. I have a launcher and 5 applications. Applications are launched using the launcher applications. How can I collect the entire project into 1 executing file and run it using it? My project built on Gradle.

**What are the ways to solve my problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to do this for modern JavaFX applications is to use jpackage which comes with JDK 14. Don't try executable jars. They won't work in general.

If you have to, you can use JDK 14+ just for jpackage but bundle your app with any JDK 11+. Just have a look here for a tutorial: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Answer (score 1):

Try using **Launch4J** (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) or **Advanced Installer** (https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) to package your .jar files into a single (or multiple) .exe file(s). Note that these are third-party programs which will enable you to package your .jar files and deploy most probably on your client's computer.

For more info read,

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html
- https://www.genuinecoder.com/convert-java-jar-to-exe/